# Phising en mi sitio web con SPF configurado

Tags: seguridad

Me estan realizando **phising** en mi sitio web con mi servicio de **mailing**. Tengo configurada la siguiente regla de **SPF**. Todo lo envio via **office 365**.

`v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all`

Que puedo hacer?

Gracias.

Saludos,